# Typescript complex constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my scenario, I'm actually new to Typescript so i don't know if this is doable. Here we go, i have a class

```
export class XClass {
    constructor(
        public a?: string,
        public b?: string
    ) {
    }
}
```

I need this XClass on another class

```
export class YClass {
    constructor(
        public xClass?: XClass ,
        public c?: string
    ) {
    }
}
```

Then i will use it like this.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <table name="xClass" id="field_xClass" [(ngModel)]="yClass.xClass">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td contenteditable="true" name="a" id="field_a" [(ngModel)]="yClass.xClass.a"></td>
                    <td contenteditable="true" name="b" id="field_b" [(ngModel)]="yClass.xClass.b"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

But im getting a lot of problems like "Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'xClass'" if xClass is null and "TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of null" if xClass.a is null.

Comment: Could you provide a stackblitz real example of your code to see the errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine was able to solve the problem, what he did was removed [(ngModel)]="yClass.xClass" and instead of using

`<td contenteditable="true" name="a" id="field_a" [(ngModel)]="yClass.xClass.a"></td>`

he used

`<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="xClass_a" id="field_xClass_a [ngModel]="yClass?.xClass?.a" (ngModelChange)="yClass.xClass.a = $event" /></td>`

Now the only issue i'm getting is if i edit 'a' field i'm getting this 
TypeError: Cannot set property 'a' of null.

I've tried hard coding default values after the constructor on YClass but it's not working.

Done. I populate the default values on ngOnInit()
this.yClass.xClass = this.yClass.xClass ? this.yClass.xClass : {a : '', b : ''};

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Angular, but if the only problem is that you need to make sure `xClass` is never null, you could initialize it like this:

```
export class YClass {
    constructor(
        public xClass?: XClass,
        public c?: string
    ) {
        if (this.xClass == null) {
            this.xClass = new XClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error still exists. Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'xClass'

Comment: Another guess: try removing `[(ngModel)]="yClass.xClass"`.

Comment: Yes if i remove [(ngModel)]="yClass.xClass" the problem is removed but how do i bind the changes made on the tds?